# c++ converting const char* to char* for long buffer

Tags: c++, char

I have an old function which I can't change the API

```
void TraceMsg(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    if (!m_MessageFunctions[TraceLevel]) return;

    char msgBuffer[MAX_LOG_MSG];
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    vsnprintf(msgBuffer, MAX_LOG_MSG, fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    m_MessageFunctions[TraceLevel](msgBuffer);
}
```

MAX_LOG_MSG = 2048

I got into a phase where I would like to allocate more space for the messages for the logger in a dynamic way

I have read this article: https://code-examples.net/en/q/4904e5
and changed my code into:

```
void TraceMsg(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    if (!m_MessageFunctions[TraceLevel]) return;

    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    size_t size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0,fmt, argList);
    char* msgBuffer = new char[size];

    vsnprintf(msgBuffer, size, fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);
    m_MessageFunctions[TraceLevel](msgBuffer);
    delete[] msgBuffer;
}
```

how ever I get wierd characters like

```text
2022-05-03 12:13:20,939 INFO  Make graph edge Bayer@LSC_1_2 ->Input@DeMux_LSC§§§§н
2022-05-03 12:13:20,939 INFO  Make graph edge Bayer@RGB_IR_2_0 ->0@Mux_X2B_BP§§§§нннннњйн‚€нннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннн
```

Can you please help?

Comment: BTW, you must not reuse `argList` for the second `vsnprintf`. You must `va_end(argList); va_start(argList, fmt);` to get a fresh `argList`.

Comment: Also, better use `unique_ptr` instead of manual `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: in windows this code works nicely, on linux I get 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106    ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: @user3840170 sorry I am new to unique_ptr can you show me how to do it for char array?

Comment: `auto msgBuffer = std::make_unique<char []>(size + 1);` instead of the `char* msgBuffer = new char[size];` line, and just drop the `delete[]` line. You need the `<memory>` header. And you need to refer to the buffer as `&msgBuffer[0]` instead of `msgBuffer` directly to get a `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `vsnprintf` is

> The number of characters that would have been written if n had been
> sufficiently large, **not counting the terminating null character**.

So you need to add 1 to this to make room for the null terminator.

Comment: Also (related), note that *At most buf_size-1 characters are written.* [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf)